# import numpy array wrapper

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following code:

```
x = array([-273.0, -176.4, -79.8, 16.9, 113.5, 210.1, 306.8, 403.4, 500.0])
y = array([2.25927498e-53, 2.56028619e-03, 8.64512988e-01, 6.27456769e+00, 1.73894734e+01,
        3.29052124e+01, 5.14612316e+01, 7.20531200e+01, 9.40718450e+01])
```

but `array()` is not recognized by the IDE, so I figure the code is using some sorta method to wrap `numpy.array`. So I added

```
import numpy.array as array
```

on the top, and the IDE is no longer complaining about using `array()`. However, when I run this code, I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.array'
```

So how do I use `array()` like a buildin function?

Comment: Normally we do `import numpy as np` and `np.array(...)`.  `array` is function in the `numpy` module.  It can be imported by name or with the `*`, but the `np.array(...)` syntax is clearer and widely used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
from numpy import array
x = array([-273.0, -176.4, -79.8, 16.9, 113.5, 210.1, 306.8, 403.4, 500.0])

print(type(x))
#<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```